# doing a pop-up login window with facebook php sdk

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, sdk, popup

I understand quite well that I can set cookies with the facebook javascript sdk but I will like to know how to access the /me profile object created on my cookies with php because there is need for me to store it on some user details on my backend. My reason for using js sdk is to allow  me use a pop-up login window for my facebook connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is client side. Only javascript can open a pop-up login window. But that's not a problem. You are misunderstanding how authentication is stored.

Authentication is achieved via cookies. Javascript can auth the user in a pop-up window(which sets the cookies), and then ping an endpoint on your server via ajax. Then your server can use the Facebook PHP SDK (which will pull the authentication data from the cookies), and make an authenticated call to the Graph API.